# Создание маски дорог на основе спутникового снимка с помощью преобразования Хафа

Tags: c#, обработка-изображений, emgucv, маска

Необходимо создать маску дорог (то есть дороги белые, все остальное черное) на основе спутникового снимка. Решил писать программу на C#, для этого взял библиотеку EmguCV. Прочитал немного об этом, но ничего толкового не нашел. Взял снимок, сделал его черно-белым, затем, с помощью фильтра Canny, обработал изображение и сохранил 40к изображений с различными параметрами фильтра (хз, зачем так много). Но особо не помогла. Фильтр выделил края, но вот что дальше делать не знаю, поэтому решил идти другим путем: просто увеличил контрастность черно-белого изображения, чтоб выделить дороги белым. Получилось не идеально, но уже что-то. Потом нашел в EmguCV пару функций Хафа, одна для прямых, вторая для кругов (ну это я так понял). Но проблема в том, что она просто записывает какие-то координаты на изображении. И вот, что с этими точками делать я не знаю. Если кто-то знаком с этим, прошу у вас помощи. Заранее благодарю.